# Filter rows that contain a string from a vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking for a function that takes a dataframe column, checks if it contains text from a vector of strings, and filters it upon match (including a partial text match).

For example, take the following data frame:

```
animal     |count
aardvark   |8
cat        |2
catfish    |6
dog        |12
dolphin    |3
penguin    |38
prairie dog|59
zebra      |17
```

And the following vector

```
c("cat", "dog")
```

I'd like to run through the 'animal' column, checking if the value fully or partially matches by one of the strings in the vector, and filter out the ones that aren't. The resulting data frame would be:

```
animal     |count
cat        |2
catfish    |6
dog        |12
prairie dog|59
```

Comment: Use `grepl`: as `df[grepl("(cat|dog)", df$animal),]` should work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We can use `grep`

```
df1[grep(paste(v1, collapse="|"), df1$animal),]
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
df1 %>%
    filter(grepl(paste(v1, collapse="|"), animal))
```

Answer (score 21):

Using `dplyr`, you can try the following, assuming your table is `df`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
animalList <- c("cat", "dog")
filter(df, str_detect(animal, paste(animalList, collapse="|")))
```

I personally find the use of `dplyr` and `stringr` to be easier to read months later when reviewing my code.

Comment: I am not sure how this works, as the 'animal' column doesn't have an exact match.

Comment: What is the structure of the actual data frame? Do we have a reproducible example including toy data?

Comment: The issue with this is that it only filters exact matches (cat and dog), and not partial matches (catfish and prairie dog). I should have specified that.  I appreciate the look, though.

Comment: NP. Added partial matching solution.

Comment: When the list of patterns are long, this solution works well. Otherwise, invalid regular expression error would have been raised.

Answer (score 1):

For large datasets the following `base R` approach can do the job 15x faster than accepted answer. At least that was my experience.

The code generates a new dataframe to store the subsets of rows that match a given value (animal).

```
#Create placeholder data frame
new_df <- df[0, ]

#Create vector of unique values
animals <- unique(df$animal)

#Run the loop
for (i in 1:length(animals)){
    temp <- df[df$animal==animals[i], ] 
    new_df <- rbind(new_df,temp)
}
```

Comment: You could make this a bit more efficent by ``setDT(df)`` and ``new_df = rbindlist(lapply(animals, function(x) {df[animal == x]}))``