# Check if a string contains at least one element from a vector

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I have the below sample dataset. I would like to filter the dataset `df` based on the value of `o3.cpt` column. I want to keep `o3.cpt` column's rows that contain any of element in `joint` vector. Is there a way to achieve this using `filter` and `str_detect` functions together?

###### Sample Dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
  library(tibble)
  
  rename <- dplyr::rename
  select <- dplyr::select
  
  joint <- c(27130, 27132, 27134, 27137, 27138, 27445, 27447, 27486, 27487)
  
  df <-
    data.frame(
    oid = seq(1, 7),
    o3.cpt = c("27130I", "33333", "27134RI", "11111", "27138", "44444", "66666")
    )


 # I would like to filter the dataset `df` based on the value of `o3.cpt`. 
  # I want to keep `o3.cpt` column's rows that contain any of element in `joint` vector.
  # When done correctly, it will filter only the row 1, row 3, and row 5. 
  # The string after each five-digit number can vary (not just 'I' or 'RI').
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gsub` to remove all non-digital characters (or `substr` to keep the first `5` digits only) and `%in%` for filtering

```
> subset(df, gsub("\\D", "", o3.cpt) %in% joint)
  oid  o3.cpt
1   1  27130I
3   3 27134RI
5   5   27138

> subset(df, substr(o3.cpt, 1, 5) %in% joint)
  oid  o3.cpt
1   1  27130I
3   3 27134RI
5   5   27138
```

Comment: why not `grep`?

Comment: @M-- I guess `grep` is slower and not vectorized.

Comment: I mean... we can do this: ```df[grep(paste(joint, collapse="|"), df$o3.cpt),]```. And it is faster than `gsub`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyJnj.png (not by an order of magnitude, but faster nonetheless). p.s. Besides that, here we are assuming that `joints` will consist of 5-digit numbers. If it had any other patterns/strings, then `gsub` won't work.

Comment: ... were you talking about `substr`? That **is** faster. But then has the same issue if the patterns were different.

Comment: @M-- Thanks for the benchmarking. I don't know if `grep` would scale well if `joint` is a long vector. Regarding `substr`, I just got the information for OP's description: *"The string after each five-digit number can vary (not just 'I' or 'RI')"*, so I thought it might have fixed locations to the desired part of the strings.

Comment: I used both `grep` and the existing solution posted in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38724690/filter-rows-that-contain-a-string-from-a-vector. Thank you very much for all your help and discussion!

Answer (score 1):

You can "collapse" `joint` using regex's OR operator `|` to make one regex pattern matching any of the components of `joint`.

```
df |>
  filter(str_detect(o3.cpt, paste(joint, collapse = "|")))
#   oid  o3.cpt
# 1   1  27130I
# 2   3 27134RI
# 3   5   27138
```

Comment: Thank you! It is same as the existing solution posted in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38724690/filter-rows-that-contain-a-string-from-a-vector. I ended up using the exact same code. Thank you very much!